# is the 16-bit length identification from the IP packet header big enough?

Tags: ip, fragment, packet, identification

I am just wondering such a simple question.

As far as I know, the identification, which is a 2-octet length data, is used to identify datagrams when fragments are made, however, the maximum number capable of a 16-bit integer is 65536, so my question is, what will happen when we've more than 65536 datagrams to send in a short time?

thanks in advance and sorry for the poor English :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 4963](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4963.txt) Abstract:

> IPv4 fragmentation is not sufficiently robust for use under some
>      conditions in today's Internet.  At high data rates, the 16-bit IP
>      identification field is not large enough to prevent frequent
>      incorrectly assembled IP fragments, and the TCP and UDP checksums are
>      insufficient to prevent the resulting corrupted datagrams from being
>      delivered to higher protocol layers.  This note describes some easily
>      reproduced experiments demonstrating the problem, and discusses some
>      of the operational implications of these observations.

Comment: yes, the identification i mean is in the IP datagram header :), so the answer is, no?

Comment: I would have sworn the question said UDP, not IP. Oy veh.

Comment: @JayC, sorry for the misleading writing `datagram` :D

Comment: Yes - re-assembly of fragmented packets can be botched when more than 64k packets are transmitted in a short time period due to the Identification field rolling over.

Comment: The maximum packet lifetime of 30 seconds, mentioned in the RFC, is an eternity in a gigabit network.  Of course, measures can be taken to stretch what's available but it's definitely an issue for IPv4 especially in naive implementations.